# Why does hash[:symbol]++ not increase the value of :symbol by one?

Tags: ruby

```
likedict={linux:3,web:2}
likedict[:linux]++
likedict[:linux]
# => 6 
likedict[:web]
# => 2
```

I figured out that `likedict[:linux]+=1` is what I want. This is my test case. I expected `likedict[:linux]` to become `4` after I do `likedict[:linux]++`, but it is `6`. Why is that?

Comment: what you have done is `likedict[:linux] + likedict[:linux]` ruby does not support `++` use `+= 1` if you need to increment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby there is no `++` operation.

If you look carefully after you do `likedict[:linux]++` it still expects more for your statement, and then you entered `likedict[:linux]`, so `3 + 3 = 6`.